# update table using nested subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have two table where I want to update one of the tables using info from another table.

```
create table CUSTOMER
(CID number(6),
First_Name varchar2(12),
Last_Name varchar2(12),
Category varchar2(7),
Balance_Due number(4,2),
SponsorID number(6),
CONSTRAINT pkCID PRIMARY KEY (CID),
CONSTRAINT fkCUSTOMER foreign key (sponsorID) references customer);
```

And the table I want to update:

```
create table BOOK_COPY
(Copy_Num number(5),
Bookid  number(5),
out_to_CID number(6),
Date_Out date,
Date_Due date,
Held_Until date,
held_for_CID number(6),
CONSTRAINT PKCOPY PRIMARY KEY (Copy_Num,Bookid),
CONSTRAINT FKCID FOREIGN KEY (out_to_CID) references CUSTOMER (CID),
CONSTRAINT FKHeld FOREIGN KEY (held_for_CID) references CUSTOMER (CID),
CONSTRAINT FKBookid FOREIGN KEY (Bookid) references BOOK (Bookid));
```

What I want to do is update BOOK_COPY so date_due = Date_out + 90 where category=faculty

Also I would like to be able to update more than one category using a case when.

I can update if I dont have the "where category='faculty'" clause in my statement. But I get an syntax error when I try to get the customer table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have different periods for different categories, I would suggest:

```
update book_copy b
    set date_due = (case (select category from customer c where c.cid= b.out_to_cid)
                        when 'faculty' then date_out + 90
                        when 'administrator' then date_out + 120
                        when 'student' then date_out - 10
                        else date_due
                    end);
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon!
When I execute the command I get no erros, but date due is not updated. Do you know why?

Comment: @JacobLindbergSørensen . . . That would occur when there is no match in the `customer` table or when the matched text is different from the `when` clauses.  Depending on how your database is set up, even case might make a difference, so you could do `select lower(category) . . . ` in the subquery.